# redirect URL if it contains keyword, take the visited URL, remove the keyword and add something to the front

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm sorry if the title is a little confusing, it is easier to explain with examples. I'd like to take this URL and all URLS that contain `find-in-set-any`

`http://www.example.com/orange/find-in-set-any/most-popular-products/find-in-set-any?limitstart=0`

and redirect it to:

`http://www.example.com/our-products/orange/most-popular-products?limitstart=0`

so I have removed all instances of `find-in-set-any` but left any `?` stuff at the end

This is also slightly more confusing in that we have language subdomains so the original URL could be

`http://www.example.com/bg/orange/find-in-set-any/most-popular-products/find-in-set-any?limitstart=0`

or

`http://www.example.com/fr/orange/find-in-set-any/most-popular-products/find-in-set-any?limitstart=0`

or any one of the 58 different language subdomains.

and I'd like to keep the existing language subdomain.

I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. Any help would be much appreciated.

In regards to rules already tried I'm trying this atm as I thought I'd split it into parts:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} find-in-set-any
RewriteRule ^/find-in-set-any(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But I must be completely wrong as I can't get it to have any effect.

EDIT

So the latest I have is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} find-in-set-any
RewriteRule (.*)find-in-set-any(.*) $1 $2 [N]
RewriteRule (.*)find-in-set-any/ $1 $2 [N]
RewriteRule (/)find-in-set-any(/) $1 $2 [N]
```

I'm pretty sure that's not the most efficient way of doing it. All I'm left with is adding our-products before it which is complicated by the presence of around 50 language subdomains `fr/` `bg/` `de/` etc. There are also 2 or 3 4 digit ones like `zh-CN` and `zh-TW`

Comment: You can also share the rules you have tried.

Comment: THanks Rahil, this what I have so far although I'm not sure it's the best way:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} find-in-set-any
RewriteRule (.*)find-in-set-any(.*) $1 $2 [N]
RewriteRule (.*)find-in-set-any/ $1 $2 [N]

Comment: I just need now to find a way to add /our-products/ in, which is complicated by the foreign language subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} find-in-set-any
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:(/[^/]+))?/([^/]+)/find-in-set-any/([^/]+)/find-in-set-any [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/our-products/%2/%3 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

This will only redirect this url:

`http://www.example.com/fr/orange/find-in-set-any/most-popular-products/find-in-set-any?limitstart=0`

to

`http://example.com/fr/our-products/orange/most-popular-products?limitstart=0`

Comment: Thanks Rahil. That is very helpful. In the case of there not being a language subdomain present at all would that require copying the whole rule and simply removing the  %1/  from after host or is there a more efficient way? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user1021330 See my edit. It will handle both cases now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahil. That has helped a lot!

Comment: Hi Rahil. I have a small problem in that this URL is not matched: http://www.example.com/orange/find-in-set-any?limitstart=0

Comment: The rule seems to only match if there are two instances of find-in-set-any but the URLs could be like:

http://www.example.com/orange/find-in-set-any/black/find-in-set-any/white/find-in-set-any?limitstart=0

or they could be simply be:


http://www.example.com/orange/find-in-set-any?limitstart=0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user1021330 Can you list down all urls to your question. This would become more complex and messy if there are too many.